# How to debug localhost redirect issue?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, localhost

I am trying to figure out why when I access my local IP (`192.168.x.x`) from another PC does not redirect to `localhost` of my PC.

My configuration is this:

I have a hypervisor on my server. On the hypervisor I have a VM with Ubuntu Server 18. In Ubuntu I have installed a Docker container with [ERPNext app](https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker). The app is available at `http://localhost` on host VM, but when I want to access the local IP of VM (from another machine) I got a `404 page not found`. If the containers are down I got an error page: `this site can't be reached`.

For more informations, I also post this question on [ERPNext Discuss Forum](https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/how-can-i-make-erp-available-in-lan/65392/14).

Comment: How did you create and run your container?

Comment: The ERP project has a `docker-compose.yml` file. So with command `docker-compose --project-name erp up -d`

Answer (score 0):

It seems someone from ERPNext already answered this question on ERPNext Discuss Forum. I'm going to copy the solution here for future reference.

1. Add following labels to `erpnext-nginx` service

```yaml
      - "traefik.http.routers.erpnext-nginx.rule=HostRegexp(`{catchall:.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.erpnext-nginx.headers.customrequestheaders.Host=erpnext-nginx"
      - "traefik.http.routers.erpnext-nginx.middlewares=erpnext-nginx"
```

to get the following configuration of the service:

```yaml
  erpnext-nginx:
    image: frappe/erpnext-nginx:${ERPNEXT_VERSION}
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - FRAPPE_PY=erpnext-python
      - FRAPPE_PY_PORT=8000
      - FRAPPE_SOCKETIO=frappe-socketio
      - SOCKETIO_PORT=9000
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.erpnext-nginx.rule=Host(${SITES})"
      - "${ENTRYPOINT_LABEL}"
      - "${CERT_RESOLVER_LABEL}"
      - "traefik.http.services.erpnext-nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.erpnext-nginx.rule=HostRegexp(`{catchall:.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.erpnext-nginx.headers.customrequestheaders.Host=erpnext-nginx"
      - "traefik.http.routers.erpnext-nginx.middlewares=erpnext-nginx"
    volumes:
      - sites-vol:/var/www/html/sites:rw
      - assets-vol:/assets:rw
```

2. Copy `env-local` to `.env` and change `mysite.localhost` to `erpnext-nginx`

```
cp env-local .env

# change mysite.localhost to erpnext-nginx
sed -i -e "s/mysite.localhost/erpnext-nginx/g" .env
```

> NOTE: recommended to use exact versions like (frappe v12.9.1 and
> erpnext v12.11.2) instead of edge or v12 tag

3. Add a file `sites/currentsite.txt` e.g. execute in container

```
echo erpnext-nginx > currentsite.txt
```

refer [here](https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker/blob/develop/docs/site-operations.md#edit-configs)

- This configuration sets default site for the deployment.
- traefik labels: these tell all the incoming requests to be reverse proxied to `erpnext-nginx` container and also sets the Host header to `erpnext-nginx`.
- `erpnext-nginx` container gets host header as `erpnext-nginx` irrespective of any site input in request and serves the site mentioned in `currentsite.txt`, `erpnext-nginx`